# How to set imageButton click to open another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, crash, android-imagebutton

How to set imageButton click to open another layout? I know there are some other questions and answers too.

My Android Emulator (Pixel with API level 25) crashes if I try answers in Stack Overflow.

I'm using Android Studio.

Please help me with this problem!

Edit:

logcat:`--------- beginning of crash
05-08 09:17:42.654 2860-2860/com.tivj_dev.applauncher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.tivj_dev.applauncher, PID: 2860
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method back(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'Backki'
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`

Comment: But it's not helped me. My app still crashes when I'm pressing that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation.

First you must define onClickListener for your button:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

And then you must define Intent, so that you will be able to eneter another activity with different layout.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourAnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

So the whole thing will be like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

 final ImageButton = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourAnotherActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

Comment: I used your code, but my app crashes still. I used Pixel (API level 25) and Pixel C (API 25).

Comment: But did you create new Activity? This code will work, if you create new Activity called YourAnotherActivity. You can later change its name

Comment: Still, it's not working.

Comment: But what exactly happening? Did you create new activity with new layout as i said? All steps you need to get it work was described by me.

Comment: Yes. I think so. I checked it and it's clear.

Comment: So what is the error? Paste it here. Do you manage it?

Comment: When I launch my app and open the layout and click the ImageButton my app craches. If you want I can write for you GitHub link.

Comment: Lol, simply paste your logcat here :) You have the information what was the cause of it, and the name of Exception

Comment: I don't know why the app crashes. Do you want to get link to GitHub?

Comment: It crashes, and there is the Exception logs in your logcat, telling you why it happened. Go to Android Monitor tab in Android Studio, and see what is there when your app crashes

Comment: It's too long to be comment, I paste it to question.

Comment: ok, paste the github also here

Comment: https://github.com/TIVJ-dev/App_launcher

Comment: The error button (Backki) is in copyright layout.

Comment: I add a working solution in Issues tab in your repo. Please accept my answer here, when you apply changes :)

Comment: It is working! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143678/discussion-between-okset-and-kuvaaja).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add it to the Manifest file.
Code:

```
<activity android:name="YourAnotherActivity" />
```

Comment: It's not working.